# Best practice to switch +V or GND connection?

Tags: power, switches, ground

Consider `LAMP1` and `LAMP2` in the simple example circuit below:

[image: CircuitLab Schematic 543n7p]

Which is the "better" practice, using the switching component (here `RLY1`) to break the `+V` connection to a component that's always connected to `GND`, like `LAMP2`; or use it to break the `GND` connection to a component that's always connected to `+V`, like `LAMP1`?

I understand that from a purely theoretical perspective it makes no difference… But my "practical intuition" insists that `LAMP2` is a better practice, because it's always grounded; thus you cannot inadvertently energize the circuit with an accidental short to ground. And yet, it seems like many (if not all) example circuits I look at connect things like `LAMP1`. So probably that means my intuition is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In practice it is best to switch the `hot` terminal, `+V` in your case. Ground is often connected to safety ground and as such has same potential as the world around you. When you unscrew a light bulb from its fitting, you don't want to accidentally get zapped when you touch the metals.

BTW it it also good practice to connect null to the outer terminal of the light bulb because of exactly the same reason: it is easier to accidentally touch.

With electronic circuits on the other hand, often the low side is switched with a transistor. This is in part because old logic parts were much easier made to be able to sink more current to GND than they could source current from Vcc. This is in turn caused by the fact that it used to be easier to manufacture NPN transistors and N-channel MOSFETs. Today PNP and P-channel MOSFETs are not too much of a problem, but you can still find better specs for NPN and N-channel in the datasheet. The main difference is with the 'majority carriers', either free electrons (for NPN and N-channel FETs) or free 'holes' (missing electrons for PNP and P-channel FETs). Electrons move quicker through the semiconductor material than holes. Hence low side switching with transistors is usually preferred.

Comment: So… my intuition was correct? Then does it make a difference if all of the components are on a PCB? Why do I see so many cases of e.g. a transistor being used to switch the `GND` connection of a circuit that's always attached to the power rails?

Comment: updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

High voltage devices are best switched from the high side, so that when they are off, no part of the device is live. When people change light bulbs, they assume it is safe to do so when they simply switch off the light.

The low side is often switched in transistor circuits because:

1. Switching the load from the high side requires a high threshold voltage unless some additional biasing brings it down. Example: 25 volt rail, PNP transistor: switch threshold is at around 24.3 volts.
2. High side load switching inverts the polarity: high means off, low means current flow.

So to rephrase that, whenever a small voltage controls the transistor as a switch, and high/low means on/off, respectively, it's simplest to put the load above the transistor.