# SPST rocker switch wiring for LED strip

Tags: led-strip, toggle-switch

Is this the correct way to wire a rocker switch to LED strip?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fakjWX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A lot of what I see online is people showing SPST 3-terminal switches for this application. Can I just use a 2-terminal like the one shown in the diagram?

Comment: If your LED strip is compatible with 12V and your switch is rated to carry the LED current then I can't see a problem.

Comment: You can use 2-terminal switch. But you need to connect a resistor in series with the LED for limiting the current through it.

Comment: I'm just a bit worried because all I see are 3-terminal switches being shown online. Would you always put the switch on the hot wire?

Comment: The current is limited to 2 amps by the AC/DC adapter.

Comment: A 2 terminal switch is just a 3 terminal switch with one contact cut off.  Ignore the "normally closed" contact and just use the "common" and "normally open" contacts.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/68888/best-practice-to-switch-v-or-gnd-connection

Comment: "The current is limited to 2 amps by the AC/DC adapter." I know this isn't the focus of your original question, but please elaborate on this. Is the adapter limited to or rated at 2 amps? There's a big difference between the two.

Comment: I guess I didn't know there was a difference. It's rated at 2 amps. What could be a potential issue?

Comment: The LED strip could draw more than 2A, which would lower the voltage on the supply but not necessarily enough to prevent the strip from drawing current. This could damage the strip. OTOH, most 12V-rated strips include enough current limiting in the form of resistors that they won't draw more than their required current regardless when connected to a 12V supply.

Comment: "Limited" means the product was designed to actively limit the current. So if you shorted the + and - lines together, it would actively reduce the voltage so the current was no more than 2A. "Rated" just means the manufacturer promises it will supply up to 2A without damage. If you attach a load that pulls more than 2A, the power supply may experience any number of failures, including overheating and melting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the LED strip works with the power supply alone, adding the switch in between is fine. The third terminal on a SPDT switch provides an alternate path for the power supply, but is usually not connected in this configuration regardless.

Comment: I think I understand after re-watching a youtube video of someone using a third terminal. They ended up just connecting both ground wires to the same terminal which, I'm guessing, is just making it a SPST switch. Does that sound right?

Comment: Also, are a lot of people incorrectly calling a 3-terminal switch a SPST, when it should be called a SPDT?

Comment: "Single Pole (one common) Double Throw (two positions)". Three terminals total. It can be used to replace a SPST by leaving one of the throws unconnected, but it is still a SPDT.

Comment: I was checking out this person's video and others like it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQpQWFYX524

Answer (score 2):

The switch used in the video  youtube.com/watch?v=cQpQWFYX524 is a lighted SPST switch.  It includes an LED connected between one switch terminal and the third pin, as below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyEgl7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A plain SPST switch (no light) will only have two terminals.  An unlighted switch with three terminals would be SPDT.